# How to set the link-title as Linktext with f:link.typolink viewhelper in TYPO3 9.5

Tags: fluid, typo3-9.x

I have build a custom content element with a link from field "header_link".

How can I set the title of that link as link text?

In the fluid template I use the link.typolink viewhelperin this way:

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="{data.header_link}" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

This results in

```
<a href="/page" title="link title" class="btn btn-primary">Page Title</a>
```

How do I set the link title as link text instead of the page title?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

since TYPO3 10.3 it can be done like this

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="{data.header_link}" parts-as="parts">
  {parts.title}
</f:link.typolink>
```

read more in the [changelog documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.3/Feature-90026-ExposeInternalTypoLinkPartsInTypolinkViewHelper.html)

these are all the parts u can use

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="123 _top news title" parts-as="parts">
   {parts.url}
   {parts.target}
   {parts.class}
   {parts.title}
   {parts.additionalParams}
</f:link.typolink>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="{data.header_link}" title="Title Attribute">
    Custom Link Text
</f:link.typolink>
```

results in

```
<a href="/page" title="Title Attribute">
    Custom Link Text
</a>
```

#### Reference

- https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Link/TypolinkViewHelper.html

---

#### Update 1

(updated from additional comments)

Combined parameter string `t3://page?uid=123 - - "title"` (`parameter` `target` `class` `title` `additional parameters`) is supposed to only have affect on generating the anchor tag. There is no out-of-the-box way to use the `title` part as variable in a Fluid template.

In order to do that, a custom ViewHelper would have to be created, e.g.

```
class ParameterPartViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
{
    public function initializeArguments()
    {
        $this->registerArgument('part', 'string', 'Parameter part to be extracted', true);
    } 

    public function render(): string
    {
        $part = $this->arguments['part'] ?? null;
        $typoLinkCodec = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TypoLinkCodecService::class);
        return $typoLinkCodes->decode($this->renderChildren())[$part] ?? '';
    }
```

That could be used in Fluid e.g. like this

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="{data.header_link}" title="Title Attribute">
    {data.header_link -> my:parameterPart(part:'title')}
</f:link.typolink>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, Oliver,  I know, that I can put the "Custom Link Text" between <f:link.typolink></f:link.typolink> but how can I **get** the title of the link, which I have set in the TYPO3 BE?

<f:debug>{data.header_link}</f:debug> gives me

t3://page?uid=123 - - "title"

My question is:  how can I get the title attribut to put it in your  "Custom Link Text"

Comment: The `title` part of the combined `parameter` string is supposed to be used as `title` attribute in `typolink` handling - thus, there is no out-of-the-box way in parsing and accessing that value.
Using `(new TypoLinkCodecService())->decode($headerLink)['title']` in a custom ViewHelper would allow to access that information (seems to be a nice and useful feature request).

Comment: Thanks, for your detailed help. To include it in the original Viewhelper would be a nice and useful Feature indeed.

Comment: Please see https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/62769 as Feature for TYPO3 v10

Comment: That's great. Therefore I love the whole opensource community thing,  thanks a lot, Oliver.

Comment: Oliver, I have a further question: is here any possibility to set the title of a content element as link text instead of the page title, if I link to the CE as an anchor link within the link wizard?

Comment: Can you fix your code please?!
In line: 12 ->
return $typoLinkCodes->decode($this->renderChildren())[$part] ?? '';
it must be "$typoLinkCodec" (Codec, not Codes)